# print page numbers problem / for i in range(0, 1440, 72)

Tags: python

I'm having problem with print page numbers for my web-scraper.

Here I have page range

```
# total 20 pages
for i in range(0, 1440, 72):
    print('scraping page' + str(i))
```

It shows me result as

```
scraping page0
scraping page72
scraping page144
scraping page216
scraping page288
scraping page360
scraping page432
scraping page504
scraping page576
scraping page648
scraping page720
scraping page792
scraping page864
scraping page936
scraping page1008
scraping page1080
scraping page1152
scraping page1224
scraping page1296
scraping page1368
```

I want to maintain '72' offset value.

But want my print result like follows.

How can I print result like this?

```
page 1
page 2
page 3
...
page 19
page 20
```

Comment: Maybe just use `tqdm` package for fancy progress bars?

Comment: @AlexeyLarionov How to do that? Could you show me an example?

Comment: Install tqdm, then `from tqdm import tqdm`, then  `for i in tqdm(range(0, 1440, 72))` without printing anything in your loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you always have an offset of 72, you can print it with

```
print(f"page {i // 72 + 1}")
```

Comment: Simple is the best.

Comment: I'm happy that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

something like the below. use `enumerate`

```
for idx, i in enumerate(range(0, 1440, 72)):
    print(f'scraping page {idx}. offset is {i}')
```

output

```
scraping page 0. offset is 0
scraping page 1. offset is 72
scraping page 2. offset is 144
scraping page 3. offset is 216
...
```